# Unroll lists and objects into function arguments?

Tags: javascript, arguments, argument-passing, ecmascript-5

I want to call a function with arguments from a list or object. Here's how I'd do it in Python:

```
d = {'foo': 'bar'}
a = ['can', 'haz']

f(*a, **d)
```

In JavaScript there is probably some trick using the internal `arguments` list, but I'm not sure of "the secret"!

Comment: I didn't get, means you just want to pass them as reference or something else?

Answer (score -1):

In JS you would simply send the object as is:
f({'foo' : 'bar'}, [can, haz]);